# Strange behavior of server.port property in Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, ssl, https

Actually, it is not a problem, but a strange thing I would like to understand. I use SpringBoot2 with embedded Tomcat. And I've added self-signed SSL certificate. This is pretty usual config:

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.port=8443
```

And I made a connector, to force http -> https redirect, like in many examples:

```
private Connector getHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
    }
```

If I would not specify server.port property in my config, I will see the following error:

> Description:
>
> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to
>   start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be
>   misconfigured.
>
> Action:
>
> Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process
>   that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen
>   on another port.

But if I will, I will see following:

> o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s):
>   8443 (https) 8080 (http) with context path ''

Why server.port starts to point at https port??? Even sources of springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties says that it is

```
/**
 * Server HTTP port.
 */
```

Is it ok, or I've got something strange in my server? Or this is how Conectors works? :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By default, the embedded server start on port 8080 if you don't give any value for server.port in the properties file
And you are also specifying connectors port as 8080 (connector.setPort(8080);)
Hence you are getting port conflicts.